# Making my image blurry in certain parts

Tags: html, css

My question is, how to i blur certain parts of my image?

[Codepen of project](https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/oGWxam) (You can press `Change View` > `Full Page` to see the pen like a user would.)

It has a plain white div with background images behind it.

How could I make my `.parent` have a transparent background and my `body` have blur background?

Also how could I make the background image fit to screen?

Please comment below to ask for more information if needed.

<sup>I'm sorry if there's is already a similar post about this. This is my 2nd post on this website, so I'm sorry if I'm breaking any rules.</sup>

Comment: To begin with, you misspelled "opacity" in your CSS. Get some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

## [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/eGLPoB?editors=1100)

> Also how could I make the background image fit to screen?

Use [`background-size: cover`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

> `.parent` have a transparent background

Just remove the background property. Or use transparent [`rbga` colors](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) .

> my `body` have blur background

Since the image is smaller than the background, this has been achieved naturally.

I used the [`filter`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) property, which is applied to the entire element though. As a result, you must use an additional HTML element This could be a [`pseudo element`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/), but I just used a `div`:

HTML: `<div class="background"></div>`.

CSS:

```
.background {
  background: url("https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/10908707/thumb/1.jpg");

  /* Apply major the blur filter. Change `1em` for more. */
  -webkit-filter: blur(1em);
  -moz-filter: blur(1em);
  -o-filter: blur(1em);
  -ms-filter: blur(1em);
  filter: blur(1em);

  /* Make background not move */
  position: fixed;

  /* ...and fill more than entire screen. Removes additional white sides from filter. */
  top: -1em;
  left: -1em;
  right: -1em;
  bottom: -1em;

  /* Make the element appear behind all others */
  z-index: -1;

  /* Make the background cover the entire element */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The blue filter just blurs my entire parent, not the image. The top:0, etc doesn't do anything for some reason. Position: fixed keeps it in the center, but errors my javascript.

Comment: Did you see my CodePen? The filter makes the entire element blurry, including it's children. Consequently, you have to use another element. In this case, I added the `<div class="background"></div>`

Comment: https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/oGWxam If what i'm left lift. It just blurs my background and makes my parent a blue or the image pus some color.

Comment: Okay, use this: https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/eGLPoB. Updated answer as well.

Comment: Thats good, but i want the image surrounding the parent (the main part) to not be blurr. I just want the main part to have a image blurr behind it wit a color like that, like http://i.imgur.com/7bjHvKe.png. If its not possible, ill just use some opacity with grey color.

Comment: I wanted it more like this:  i.imgur.com/7bjHvKe.png . Plus, position: fixed centers everything, but my code itself doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Did you see my most recent pen? It doesn't use fixed.

Comment: I am using your code and it just doesn't work for some reason on my side. Here is my codepen again, did something change between then and now?
 https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/oGWxam

Comment: what is different though?